# SQL - merge 2 columns into 1 from separated tables (not concat)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

baisicly I want to take from two table two columns that have the same information and combine them to one table that has one column with all the data from the other 2.

I explain with an example:

```
Table 1

ID             |      Number         |
1              |      100            |
2              |      150            |
3              |      160            |
4              |      170            |

Table 2

ID             |      Number         |
1              |      110            |
2              |      120            |
3              |      130            |
4              |      180            |


Result (With sql query that using SELECT, so i can check result):

Number
100
150
160
170
110
120
130
180
```

Comment: Look up `UNION` and or `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT Number FROM Table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT Number FROM Table_2
```

or `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` if you want to remove duplicated values